# edit review & reject help page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, rejected-edits, editing-help

So there are a quite few questions about rejected edits. Many from rattled newbies ([like me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7198769)) facing their first rejection.
And many answers boil down to one or several of the following:

- the reviewer was wrong
- the reviewer did only read the commit comment (which was barely a comment)
- the edit was too minor (to be of any help to the thread)
- the edit was wrong

First and last point of course, we can't help.

But I know now, that it is essential to elaborate on the commit comment. Drawing parallels to writing/contributing code it is of course good practice to comment commits well, but 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit  does not even mention it for edits. I think it would be worth at least a bullet point.

(Also, in the edit comment box, something like a <30 | >300 characters warning/reminder would be cool, though not sure on the numerical boundaries ;) )

And reviewers should have an equal [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), or the edit help page could cover that topic. Like a link to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) thread or a digest thereof.

Finally, I am still unsure of minor edits (like adding a hyperlink) to otherwise good or sufficient posts.

Comment: Yes, there really should be a help page for reviewers. That is a great suggestion. And FWIW, I think that edit was OK.

Comment: @TylerH: Aye, something else they won't bother reading.