# Help Center Prompt when Editing a Post

Tags: feature-request

**Possible Duplicate:** [edit review & reject help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287149/edit-review-reject-help-page)

There is a nice "asking help" link when asking a question.
[image: How to Format box showing asking help link.]

But there is no such link when editing a post.[image]

Similar links should be displayed as well in editing mode.

There are 2 excellent answers here on meta, but it would be nice not to have to dig for them.

[How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit/303220#303220)

[Should I downvote/comment/edit/ignore questions with a snarky tone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254105/should-i-downvote-comment-edit-ignore-questions-with-a-snarky-tone)